# Add +5 days to getOrderDate()

Tags: magento-1.7, localisation, date

If I use

```
<?php echo "Valid until: "; echo strtolower(date('j. M. Y', strtotime($this->getPdfHelper()->getOrderDate()." +5 days")))?>
```

I get proper result, but month is displayed in English, not in Magento locale.

If I use

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Valint until')?>: <?php echo $this->getPdfHelper()->getOrderDate() + (5*24*60*60), true, $format?><br/>
```

Result is "Valid until: 4320031"

Any suggestion, how to add days to `getOrderDate()` so result will be in Magento locale, with `"j. M. Y"` date format?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
/** @var Zend_Date $date */
$date = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date(strtotime($this->getPdfHelper()->getOrderDate() . " +5 days"));
$date->setOptions(array('format_type' => 'php'));
echo $date->toString('j.M.Y');
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, it works - shows date in correct format and language, but causes another problem. In following code, I use
<?php echo $history['date'] ?>
and now instead of correct date format, it shows 12. MMMMMMMMM. 00002014? Any idea how to solve this for both date instances?

Comment: What is $history?

Comment: <?php $commentHistory = $pdfHelper->OutputCommentHistory() ?>
<?php if ($commentHistory) : ?>
    <br/>
    <strong><?php echo Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status order') ?></strong><br/>  
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
    <?php foreach ($commentHistory as $history): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $history['date'] ?><?php if ($history['label']): ?> | <?php echo $history['label'] ?><?php endif; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $history['comment'] ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    <br/>
<?php endif; ?>